# Using if statements with user inputs

Tags: python, if-statement, user-input

I am trying to create a simple product inventory using python but for some reason the `if` statement won't run and I don't know what's wrong. Below is the output and inputs of the code.

#Code

```py
def inventory_products():
    choice = str(input("What do you want to do? \nEnter Add item, Quantity, Show Inventory:"))
    if choice == 'Add item':
        input("Enter name")
inventory_products()
```

#Output

```
What do you want to do? 
Enter Add item, Quantity, Show Inventory:Add item 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: looks like you have extra space after item

Comment: btw the `str()` around the `input()` is redundant since `input()` always returns a string.

Comment: @Tuqay not sure, but could be since yea you can highlight it :p but like ... asking such a question stackoverflow without even running the code at least one more time is a huge issue

Comment: Also the `if` works for me. I can see `Enter name` and I have to enter something for the program to end. I have to enter exactly `Add item` at the first `input()` for it to work.

Comment: This code should work.  It looks like you accidentally added a space at the end of your answer, and so the input was not exactly equal to `Add item`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def inventory_products():
    choice = str(input("What do you want to do? \nEnter Add item, Quantity, Show Inventory:"))
    if choice.strip() == 'Add item': # change in code to remove extra spaces
        input("Enter name")
inventory_products()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know about comparing strings in python click [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/string-comparison-in-python/)

but you can try this code:

```
def inventory_products():
    choice = str(input("What do you want to do? \nEnter Add item, Quantity, Show Inventory:")).lower()
    if choice.strip() == 'add item':
        input("Enter name: ")
    else:
        print("Invalid Choice!")

inventory_products()
```

So `.lower()` will convert any capital letter to small letters, so that errors can be reduced